# How to extend my hard disk into a second hard disk?

Tags: disk-management

I have two hard disks on my computer, both of which are running Ubuntu (different versions).

One of them is about to run out of disk space, and I want to get partition some of the second hard disk to use as an extension to the former.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend trying anything fancy like making one logical disk out of two physical disks. A better option would be to simply format your second hard drive using [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/). You probably want to use ext3 or ext4 if the hard drive will be Linux-only. After formatting it, simply move some lesser-used and larger files over to the second drive to make space on the first.